# How do I make my Gradle project automatically built in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am trying to use Gradle for my Java project. However, it does not automatically build like when I use Maven. Which plugins and settings should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Gradle Eclipse plugin: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html

If you are starting your project, maybe you could try STS: http://spring.io/tools/sts